# Or-Tools：glop or clp to solve a LP

Tags: or-tools

I have a linear programming problem where I use Or-Tools interface in Java for modeling. When using SCIP, I sometimes encounter memory errors and the solving time is relatively long. Later, I changed the solverType to GLOP and the solving time was about 5s. However, when I changed it to CLP, an error is reported that it cannot find a feasible solution, with a log "

> status = UNKNOWN_STATUS

".

To determine the root cause of the issue, I constructed a small linear programming problem, and found that while GLOP provided the optimal solution quickly, CLP still failed to solve it. Can anyone know what might be causing this ?

```
ModelBuilder model = new ModelBuilder();
    double infinity = java.lang.Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    Variable x = model.newNumVar(0.0, infinity, "x");
    Variable y = model.newNumVar(0.0, infinity, "y");

    System.out.println("Number of variables = " + model.numVariables());
    // x + 7 * y <= 17.5.
    model.addLessOrEqual(LinearExpr.newBuilder().add(x).addTerm(y, 7), 17.5).withName("c0");

    // x <= 3.5.
    model.addLessOrEqual(x, 3.5).withName("c1");

    System.out.println("Number of constraints = " + model.numConstraints());
    // Maximize x + 10 * y.
    model.maximize(LinearExpr.newBuilder().add(x).addTerm(y, 10.0));
    // Solve with the LP solver.
    ModelSolver solver = new ModelSolver("glop");
    final SolveStatus status = solver.solve(model);
```

GLOP
[image]

CLP
[image]

Comment: maybe the problem is the upper bound for each variable, you can try give a specific number, for example 9999 be upper bound to test out.

Comment: Strange, I recommend using glop anyway as we develop it and it is maintained. Can you add `solver.enableOutput(true);` to get some log ?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried according to your instructions, like ```double infinity = 9999;``` and ```solver.enableOutput(true);```. The solver will print many useful information when the solvertype = glop; however, when the solvertype = clp, nothing printed, just the ```The problem does not have an optimal solution!``` in red front, as the picture shows.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. model_builder is a minimal module. Currently, it supports GLOP, CP-SAT, PDLP, and SCIP.

If you print the status, it will be MPSolverResponseStatus::MPSOLVER_SOLVER_TYPE_UNAVAILABLE.

Comment: I find that to create a solver using CLP, I should use ```MPSolver solver = MPSolver.createSolver("CLP");```, instead of ```ModelSolver solver = new ModelSolver("CLP");```